# Python: Using a variable in an expression (or calling the mongoengine update function)

Tags: python, django, mongoengine

So I'm trying to call the update function in mongoengine but I need to pass in a variable. I essentially have a model with a DictField and I'm trying to see a value to it. So I have something like

In **models.py**

```
class MyDoc(Document):
    dictField = DictField()
```

**In views.py**

```
val = "some random value"
MyDoc.update(set__dictField__str(holder.id)=val)
```

But it keeps giving me an error when I try to even check the module that says

```
** keyword can't be an expression
```

When I changed it to this

```
holderId = str(holder.id)
val = "some random value"
MyDoc.update(set__dictField__holderId=val)
```

it used "holderId" as the key instead of the actual value str(holder.id) evaluated to. Is there anyway to get around this?

Comment: What arguments do you want `MyDoc.update` to receive?

Comment: I want it to perform the set dictField[holderId]=val except holderId is a variable, not the actual name of the key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at next example:

```
class MyDoc(Document):
    dictField = DictField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.dictField)

MyDoc.objects.delete()

MyDoc(dictField={'a': {'b': {'c': 5}}}).save()
print MyDoc.objects.first()
# {u'a': {u'b': {u'c': 5}}}

MyDoc.objects.update(set__dictField__a__b__c=0)
print MyDoc.objects.first()
# {u'a': {u'b': {u'c': 0}}}
```

For example if `str(holder.id)` return `id1234` then you request will look like:

```
MyDoc.objects.update(set__dictField__id1234=val)
```

or

```
MyDoc.objects.update(**{'set__dictField__' + str(holder.id): val})
```

Comment: Just for some clarification I tried doing the same thing with unset and got an error. I tried MyDoc.objects.update(**{'unset__dictField__' + str(holder.id): val}) to remove the binding and got an error saying "Cannot encode object: <ValClass: 51e94b55bc616310e5e4f3fb>

Comment: Look like `val` is not `dict`.

Comment: Wait, so how would I remove a key from a dict? Is it not using the same format except with 'unset'?